# Instance of scipy.stats.rv_discrete subclass throws error on pmf() method

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I want to create a subsclass of `scipy.stats.rv_discrete` to add some additional methods. However, when I try to access the `pmf()` method of the subclass, an error is raised. Please see the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

class sub_rv_discrete(stats.rv_discrete):
  pass

xk = np.arange(2)
pk = (0.5, 0.5)

instance_subclass = sub_rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))
instance_subclass.pmf(xk)
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-129655c38e6a>", line 11, in <module>
    instance.pmf(xk)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2832, in pmf
    args, loc, _ = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)

AttributeError: 'rv_sample' object has no attribute '_parse_args'
```

Despite that, if I use `stats.rv_discrete` directly, everything is fine:

```
instance_class = stats.rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))
instance_class.pmf(xk)

---> array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@**josef-pkt**'s answer on [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8057#issuecomment-364240817) is given below:

> going through the regular subclassing creates a rv_sample class and doesn't **init** the correct class
>
> the following works for me with 0.18.1 (which I have open right now)
>
> ```
> from scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure import rv_sample
>
> class subc_rv_discrete(rv_sample):
>
>     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
>         return super(subc_rv_discrete, cls).__new__(cls)
>
> xk = [0,1,2,3]
> pk = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
>
> inst = subc_rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))
> print(inst.pmf(xk))
> print(inst.__class__)
> ```

maybe this will be fixed in further `scipy` releases...