# Creating scipy.stats random variable subclass does not result in expected object type

Tags: python, class, scipy, statistics

I am trying to extend scipy.stats.rv_discrete to provide some simple distributions for the user. For example, in the simplest case they might want a distribution with a constant output. Here's my code for that:

```
from scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure import rv_sample

class const(rv_sample):  # a distribution with probability 1 for a single val
    def __init__(self, val, *args, **kwds):
        super(const, self).__init__(values=(val, 1), *args, **kwds)
```

However, this is not resulting in an object of the same type as the built-in random variable distributions, and this is messing up some operations I want to perform on distributions generically. Compare this to the poisson distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import inspect

print('\nThese should both contain rv_discrete:')
print('1: ', inspect.getmro(poisson.__class__))
print('2: ', inspect.getmro(const.__class__))

print('\nThese should both be rv_frozen:')
print('1: ', inspect.getmro(poisson(5).__class__))
print('2: ', inspect.getmro(const(5).__class__))
```

Output:

```
These should both contain rv_discrete:
1:  (<class 'scipy.stats._discrete_distns.poisson_gen'>, <class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_discrete'>, <class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_generic'>, <class 'object'>)
2:  (<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)

These should both be rv_frozen:
1:  (<class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen'>, <class 'object'>)
2:  (<class '__main__.const'>, <class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_sample'>, <class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_discrete'>, <class 'scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_generic'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm relatively inexperienced when it comes to subclassing so it may be something simple. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the examples on this [page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html)? What are you trying to achieve by checking the `__mro__` (method resolution order in full)?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635803/instance-of-scipy-stats-rv-discrete-subclass-throws-error-on-pmf-method) is related. Looking at this [discussion](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8057) which I think is close to what you are trying to achieve, it seems that you've just open a can of worms unfortunately. If you narrow down your question with what you are trying to achieve, there might be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Jacques. I found those questions which is how I ended up at my current state - I think the can of worms is fairly avoidable by going straight to rv_sample. If you look at the ```__new__``` method for rv_discrete ([link to source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2682-L3386)), it's pretty apparent what's going on.

Comment: I'm using the ```__mro__``` method to look at the object class hierarchy, to see what types the distribution objects . I want my custom ```const``` object to be of the same type as the built-in distributions, so I can perform similar operations on both of them.

Comment: You are never supposed to import anything from `scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure` directly. That module is an implementation detail.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to here, if you look at Jacques' and my links in the comments above. It's not possible to inherit from rv_discrete for a custom distribution due to the way its ```__new__``` method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not able to be worked around at the moment, but is part of an overhaul of scipy's distributions as being tracked here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15928